# Compile Eror: Next without for

Tags: vbaccelerator

I'm just trying to learn my code, and here it is:

```
Sub lala()
Dim ha As String
Dim objcell As Object
Dim ha2 As String
Dim ha3 As String
    For Each objcell In ActiveSheet
    MsgBox ("BLAH")
    ha = MsgBox("Do you want the same message box?", vbYesNo)
    If ha = vbYes Then
    Next objcell
    Else
    MsgBox("Do you want another one at all?", vbYesNo) = ha3
    If ha3 = vbYes Then
    ha2 = InputBox("What do you want it to say?")
    Else
    Exit Sub
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing an "if" and a "for", your "next" is in the "if" statement, while it should be outside it.
Here is your "corrected" code :

```
Sub lala()
    Dim ha As String
    Dim objcell As Object
    Dim ha2 As String
    Dim ha3 As String
    For Each objcell In ActiveSheet
        MsgBox ("BLAH")
        ha = MsgBox("Do you want the same message box?", vbYesNo)
        If ha = vbNo Then Exit for
    Next objcell
    MsgBox("Do you want another one at all?", vbYesNo) = ha3
    If ha3 = vbYes Then
        ha2 = InputBox("What do you want it to say?")
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How bout this?  I get "Compile eror:  User-Defined type not defined"  Thanks!

Comment: I did change my code a bit:Sub lala()
    Dim ha As String
    Dim this As Object
    Dim ha2 As String
    Dim ha3 As String
    For Each this In ActiveSheet
        MsgBox ("BLAH")
        ha = MsgBox("Do you want the same message box?", vbYesNo)
        If ha = vbNo Then Exit For
    Next this
    ha3 = MsgBox("Do you want another one at all?", vbYesNo)
    If ha3 = vbYes Then
        ha2 = InputBox("What do you want it to say?")
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
I get runtime eror '438': Object doesn't support this property or method, and highlights For Each this In ActiveSheet

Comment: Does my previous answer helped you? For your new question, your error probably come from the fact that "this" should be "cell" in your "for each".